# Spring Security In Memory Auth Log In Fail

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I want to use both in memory auth and `userDetailsService` auth. Beacause I have to create one `admin` account when application start and then I will create another one with form. But the first one had to in memory due to security reason.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    /* @formatter:off */
    http.authorizeRequests()

    // some configs
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .and()
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .withUser("user").password("1").roles("ADMIN");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private VendorService vendorService;

@Autowired
private AdminService adminService;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    UserDetails userAdmin = adminService.getAdminByUsername(username);

    if (userAdmin != null) {
        System.out.println(userAdmin.getUsername());
        return userAdmin;
    } else {
        UserDetails userVendor = vendorService.getVendorByUsername(username);
        if (userVendor == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user");
        }else{
            System.out.println(userVendor.getUsername());
            return userVendor;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I can login with in DB users but can't login with `user` and `1` password.

Comment: Why not to store user to the db?

Comment: I am storing user in DB. But in very first time of the application serve there is no user in DB. I solved with permit admin create page and then I create admin. But this is securoty issues because anybody can create admin with this workaround. For this reason I am trying to first in memeory admin and create actual admin.

Comment: You should store it before the first time.

Comment: But I use BCyrpt for passwordEncoder. I  can't store user without encode.

Comment: Then you encode and store it.

Comment: Got it. I will create one admin when server is fully ready if there is no admin.

Comment: But I don't understand why it doesnt working.